# converting multiple images as a byte array back into images xamarin forms

Tags: arrays, image, xamarin

Im trying to display multiple images from a folder on my server, given an id and it seems the only way to get all the images is to convert to byte array, send back to client then convert back into images. How do you convert the single byte array back into multiple images on the xamarin forms app? Or if there is a better option what is the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to convert anything. you can simply use your image url path

```
var image = new Image();
    image.Source = new UriImageSource {
    Uri = new Uri("YOUR IMAGE URL"),
    CachingEnabled = true,
    CacheValidity = new TimeSpan(4,0,0,0)
    };
Content = image;
```

But to answer your question you can init the ImageSource class from a byte[] like this

```
var image = new Image(); 
    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(YOURBYTES));
Content = image;
```

Comment: What if I'm getting images based on an Id and loading from a folder name rather than giving the individual file names?

Comment: are your image store in a database? or on the server ? I'm  confuse on how your getting an image id from your mobile app . are you assigning images ids from your xamarin app? does this make sense lol?

Comment: The images are on the server, in a folder, not the database. the operation goes I scan something, that scan will produce an id. that id is also linked to a folder on the server that contains images. But the images have random names, the only identifier I have is the folder name. So when i make a request for images, I want to call that folder with the matching id, and take all the images from that folder and send them back to the app.

Comment: The difficulty i'm having so far is breaking that byte array in the header(that contains multiple byte arrays representing the images) back into the multiple images on the app

Comment: could you provided a snippet of what your trying to doing in xamarin my understanding is your doing some kinds of web request in xamarin forms and you get back either an array or list of byte[]   or you getting one big byte[] that needs to be split??

Comment: I took your route of thinking and adopted your solution using the url instead of sending a bytestream. Thanks!